# Using Shiny with UNO Platform

Tags: mobile, integration, uno-platform

Looking for a way to use [shinyorg/shiny](https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny/tree/master/src/Shiny.Core) nuget packages in cross-platform projects built on the UNO platform.

Facing some challenges beyond my (limited) skills for iOS development, I'm specifically looking for how to integrate Shiny.Core into the solution iOS project.

More precisely, I'm looking for where to put this initialization override:

```
public override void PerformFetch(UIApplication application, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    => this.ShinyPerformFetch(completionHandler);
```

Since when I try adding this in the `Main.cs` (Application class) of the iOS project, I can't find where to start...

The `Main.cs` class from the iOS project contains a static Main method (which is the main entry point of the app) in which a call to `UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(App));` is made.

`UIApplication` being in fact `UIKit.UIApplication`

Following this guide https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny/tree/master/src/Shiny.Core where it's said:

```
* Add the following as the first line in your AppDelegate.cs - FinishedLaunching method

using Shiny;
this.ShinyFinishedLaunching(new YourStartup());


** IOS JOBS **
If you plan to use jobs in iOS, please do the following:

1. Add this to your AppDelegate.cs

public override void PerformFetch(UIApplication application, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    => this.ShinyPerformFetch(completionHandler);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS, the AppDelegate is actually the `App` class in your app, created from the default Uno Platform templates.

`Windows.UI.Xaml.Application` inherits from `UIApplicationDelegate` and provides a way declare this:

```cs
#if __IOS__
public override void PerformFetch(UIApplication application, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    => this.ShinyPerformFetch(completionHandler);
#endif
```

in order for the code for the other platforms to ignore this iOS-specific code